# Rhino JavaScript and dynamic scope var creation

Tags: javascript, dynamic, rhino

I am trying to define a dynamic variable within a function in Rhino JavaScript (specifically what is embedded in Java 6), but I don't want to resort to eval, and I don't want to have to reference it via this.  Basically, I want to take an object, and turn every property into a var within the scope of a function... something like:

```
var abc = "value";
var context = { abc: 123, xyz: "def" };

function test(cx) {
  for (var p in cx) {
    this_scope[p] = cx[p];
  }

  println(abc);
  // DON'T WANT TO HAVE TO DO THIS:
  // pritnln(this.abc);
}

test(context); // prints: 123
println(abc); // prints: value
```

Believe it or not, it is significant if I have to use "this." (it is a dynamically generated function that I want to invoke over and over with different context objects and using "this" for every variable would be **very** detrimental).

I also want to avoid having to grab a new engine context or something like that... it would be superb if I can do this straight in JavaScript (I think the result would be significantly faster).

Comment: Is this really dynamic scoping as the title suggests, or something else entirely? To me, dynamic scoping means referring to the caller's environment bindings. It's dynamic because what gets bound depends on the program execution flow. Making shorthand names for names that are already visible in a static scope seems like it's a different thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, basically you want something that works like JS's `with`? *grins, ducks, and runs*

```
var abc = "value";
var context = {abc: 123, xyz: "def"};

function test(cx) {
    with (cx) {
        println(abc);
    }
}

test(context);
println(abc);
```

Mind you, some well-known JS practitioners, like Doug Crockford, [strongly deprecate the use of `with`](http://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/).

Comment: that is PRECISELY what I was looking for... (I feel dumb now)

Comment: Be sure to take the bad aspects of `with` into consideration, that is, setting a property that doesn't exist on the current scope, does not set it on the current `with` scope, it sets in on the global scope. http://jsfiddle.net/EJM6X/

Comment: +1 for *grinning, ducking, and running* after suggesting the use of `with`.